# What should I do with all this candy corn?

Tags: guild-wars-2

This week in Guild Wars 2, you can loot [candy corn](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Piece_of_Candy_Corn) from the trick-or-treat bags randomly dropped by enemies, and mine it from candy corn veins scattered around the world.

I've found a few uses for this stuff already, but what I really what to know is what I *should* be doing with it to maximize my potential rewards from the Halloween event.

So: What should I be doing with this candy corn to maximize my potential rewards from the Halloween event?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what you're counting as rewarding (Only tangible objects? Achievements? Gold?), so I'll try to cover everything.

- Pretty much the best use for excess candy corn is to give it to the kids dressed up in costumes in Lion's Arch. You can give increments of 10 (1 bag), 20 (3 bags), and 50 candy corn (8 bags) in order to receive [Personalized Trick or Treat bags](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Personalized_Trick-or-Treat_Bag).

  Personalized Trick-or-Treat bags have a higher chance to drop the rare salvage items that you need ([Plastic Fangs](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Plastic_Fang)/[Nougat Centers](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Nougat_Center)/[Chattering Skulls](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Chattering_Skull)). You need these in order to create the recipes for the Gifts ([Gift of Spiders](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Gift_of_Spiders)/[Gift of Souls](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Gift_of_Souls)/[Gift of the Moon](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Gift_of_The_Moon)) that are required for the 3 craftable Halloween weapons, [Arachnophobia](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Arachnophobia), [The Crossing](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/The_Crossing), and [The Mad Moon](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/The_Mad_Moon).

  Note that only the *recipe* to make the Gifts requires Candy Corn, not the actual recipes for the Gifts themselves. For example, you need 250 CC+100 Nougat Centers+40 [Bottles of Elonian Wine](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Bottle_of_Elonian_Wine)+10 [Piles of Crystalline Dust](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Pile_of_Crystalline_Dust) to create the Artificer recipe for the Gift of Souls. However, the Gift of Souls itself is made up of non-Halloween items ([Gift of Knowledge](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Gift_of_Knowledge)+250 [Orichalcum Ingots](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Orichalcum_Ingot)+20 [Globs of Ecto](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Glob_of_Ectoplasm)+100 [Crystal Lodestones](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Crystal_Lodestone)), <s>which means that after you acquire the Recipe, that's all you have to worry about in regards to time-sensitive Halloween resources</s>. I forgot that you *do* need to have 20 [Superior Sigils of the Night](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Superior_Sigil_of_the_Night) for crafting any single one of these weapons (just not the Gifts), so you would also have to have a store of 2,000 CC in order to craft one of these weapons after Halloween.

  However, like many Exotics, the requirements for these weapons are a bit steep in regards to both gold cost and/or time needed to spend farming for items, so you may wish to forego them and simply flip the rare items on the Trading Post.
- Eating 150 pieces will also go towards netting you the October [Monthly Achievement](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Monthly), which will net you 20 [Mystic Coins](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Mystic_Coin) and 10 [Jugs of Liquid Karma](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Jug_of_Liquid_Karma) (you'll still have to fulfill the other requirements for the monthly). In addition, these bags will also count towards the number of Trick-or-Treat bags opened for the Special Event achievement "Trick or Treat bags opened".
- And of course, you can also hang onto it and hope that after the event ends, the demand for Candy Corn (and other Halloween-related rewards) will rise after the source of the supply has disappeared and try to flip it on the Trading Post for gold.

The other rare skins available in this event only drop from [Black Lion Chests](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Black_Lion_Chest)/[Mad King Chests](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Mad_King_Chest), so your candy corn won't increase your chance to get those.

<sub>Note that the prices for the Gifts fluctuate. Keep an eye out for the 10g mark, which is cheaper than the materials cost of the non-fluctuating vendor items (40x Bottles of Elonian Wine) required to craft the Gifts, so it may be more worth your while to outright buy them if you want to eventually craft them.</sub>

Comment: I was sure I spotted a karma vendor in Lion's Arch selling those three weapons...or maybe the recipes? I can't remember.

Comment: I think the karma vendor versions only last for 4 hours, while the craftables are permanent.

Comment: @Alex Sigh is correct, those are "rental" versions of the weapons. They cost 150 CC and only last for 4 hours. They aren't the recipes, just rented skins to allow people to run around with them for a while if they want.

Comment: Holy f---! Looking at the requirements for the Arachnophobia there is no way you'd be able to get all those items together in the timeframe. Even the sigils of night require candy corns also.

Comment: @DavidYell Ah, I forgot about the Sigils, I'll add a note about that.